# UIActivityIndicatorView stop animation

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiactivityindicatorview

I have tableview which populates data from server, I am using `UIActivityIndicatorView` to show processing icon, but if user press back button this indicator view still animating. How can we perform stopAnimating on this `UIActivityIndicatorView`? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the sample code I am using to create ActivityIndicatorView.

```
 self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    self.spinner.center = self.tableView.center;
    self.spinner.color = [UIColor yellowColor];
    UIWindow *mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    [mainWindow addSubview: self.spinner];
```

Comment: You mentioned that "user press back button", are you using `UINavigationCcontroller`?

Comment: @YuchenZhong: Yes correct. UINavigationController back button press.

Comment: Is there any reason why you add the UIActivityIndicatorView to the `keyWindow`? Do you want it to work across different views or something?

Comment: @YuchenZhong, I am learning Objective-C and I got this snippet from some example I referred. I don't need UIActivityIndicatorView across views. What should I do if I need only for this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initialization of the spinner is okay as the following:

```
self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
self.spinner.center = self.view.center;
```

And then in order to see the `spinner`, you need to add it as a subview of some view. So we will normally do the following.

```
[self.view addSubview:self.spinner];
```

However, since you are using a `tableview` here, it is not a good idea to do so. Becaue a tableview is a scroll view, and the spinner will scroll with the table view, which is super weired to the user.

Therefore, it is a better idea to add the `self.spiner` as the subview of `view` of `navgationcontroller`.

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.spinner];
```

When you tap on the back button, the spinner will go away with the table view and you don't need to worry about stopping the animation.

**Edit:**

BTW, if you want to stop animation before your view go away, for example, if you already finish communicating with the server and finish loading the data, you can always do so by calling `[self.spinner stopAnimation]`.

Comment: Thanks! I see it should be subview rather than adding to window. Let me try it, I saw somewhere that viewDisappear can be used if I continue with the code I have, what is your opinion on it?

Comment: Regarding your edit, if user waits until load finish, no problem on stopping on animation. Problem is in case where load not finished yet, but user click on back.

Comment: Yes, you can do that as well. Add `[self.spinner stopAnimating]` to `viewDidDisappear` will work. However, by default the `hidesWhenStopped` is set to `YES`. When you called `self.spinner stopAnimating`, the spinner is hidden rather than being released from the memory. And since it is created in your TableView class, no one else will even know that this spinner ever exist in your view hierarchy. So if you really don't want to change your code, do the following then: `[self.spinner stopAnimating]; [self.spinner removeFromSuperview]`.

Comment: Will it create memory leak If I have the code in my question in all my controllers? Will it create multiple instances of UIActivityIndicatorView? I have almost 10 ViewControllers viewDidLoad method with same code (which is in my question). Have can make sure this will not create a leak? Any suggestions?

Comment: It will not result in memory leak if you are using ARC. Yes, multiple `UIActivityIndicatorView` will be created every time you call [UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]. To make sure there is no memory leak, you can try suing [Instrument](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYourApp/MemoryManagementforYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH11-SW1) to detect memory leak. Great tool & easy to use. But you won't have memory leak with ARC in your case.

Comment: Great thank you! I will test it more. Will accept your answer soon.